# Insert values to table in database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

I have a Winforms application and database to save data from user.

When I insert data everything works fine but when I clean the solution and load the GUI of the database to see the old data.. I don't see the datam the datagridview is empty.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dataBase.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
   using (SqlCommand wow = new SqlCommand("insert into GamesTbl(Type,Date,Time) Values(@type,@date,@time)", con))
   {
      wow.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", "vsPC");
      wow.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now.Date);
      wow.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);

      try
      {
          con.Open();
          wow.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
   }
}
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: binding data on DBGui_load

```
private void DBGui_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = playersTblBindingSource;
        playersTblBindingSource.DataSource = DB.GamesTbls;

    }
```

EDIT: my connection string:

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated     
Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the Insert code you have written above. But where did you bind the data to your DaraGridView??

Comment: I have a Main Form with some buttons, one of the button is "DB"
when i click on it its open the GUI FORM ,so i'm binding the data when the form is load - on GUIForm_Load event

Comment: can you post that code here as well.

Comment: also when i open the table in the IDE to see the data after i close my program, the table doesn't change

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like?

Answer (score 1):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Database1` - or while you're at it - give it a more sensible name...)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Comment: thanks, so what you are saying that because it runs from the debug..
whenver i start my program the recent saved data will be lost?

Comment: @Elior: Visual Studio will copy your `.mdf` to the debug output directory, insert the data there, and then that data is gone since you're looking at the `.mdf` in your original directory

Answer (score 0):

Seems liks you are missing `DataBind`.

```
private void DBGui_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = playersTblBindingSource;
    dataGridView1.DataBind(); // you are missing this
    playersTblBindingSource.DataSource = DB.GamesTbls;
}
```

Comment: weird but i don't have this option in the dataGridView

Comment: sorry about the DataBind()... its for web application. the only reason i see why the DataGridView could be empty is bcuz of the DataSource not being proper.

Comment: so what can i do? right now this is the only table i check for insertion

Comment: i would suggest you to keep a Debugger on the line `dataGridView1.DataSource = playersTblBindingSource;` and check whats inside of `playersTblBindingSource`. If there is Data then add the same line of code after the `using` block above.

Comment: ok but when i insert some data programmatically, isn't it true that i should see the new data when i'm right clicking on the table and select 'show table data' from the IDE?

Comment: once you insert data programmatically you will have to call `dataGridView1.DataSource = playersTblBindingSource;` again to see the new data.

Comment: ok, but i mean in the mdf file there is a folder named - Tables
that contains all the tables from the database.. now after
i insert to some table a new data and close my program.. the data
should be saved on this table. but right now, when i'm inserting data and closing my program.. when i'm right clicking on the table and select show table data i don't see nothing. it means that it didn't insert the data to the table..

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, what you can do to fix the problem is to set the property of your database file in your solution as follows

`Copy To Output Directory`: `do not copy`

Comment: I tried it, and i get this error : An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ... failed

Comment: Try to remove the `User Instance = true' in your connection string. Also, try replacing the "|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf" with the full path ofyour database1.mdf